# How to configure AWS CDK Account and Region to look up a VPC

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am learning the AWS CDK, and this is a problem I can't seem to figure out. JS/Node are not languages I use often, so if there is some obvious native thing that I am missing, please don't be too harsh. I'm trying to deploy a container to an existing VPC / new ECS Cluster. The following code isn't my whole script but is an important part. Hopefully, it gives the idea of what I'm trying to do.

```js
//import everything first

stack_name = "frontend";

class Frontend extends core.Stack {
constructor(scope, id, props = {}) {
    super(scope, id);

    console.log("env variable " + JSON.stringify(props));
    
    const base_platform = new BasePlatform(this, id, props);

    //this bit doesn't matter, I'm just showing the functions I'm calling to set everything up

    const fargate_load_balanced_service = ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService();
    this.fargate_load_balanced_service.taskDefinition.addToTaskRolePolicy();
    this.fargate_load_balanced_service.service.connections.allowTo();
    const autoscale = this.fargate_load_balanced_service.service.autoScaleTaskCount({});
    this.autoscale.scale_on_cpu_utilization();
    }
}

class BasePlatform extends core.Construct {
constructor(scope, id, props = {}) {
    super(scope, id);
    this.environment_name="frontend";
    
    console.log("environment variables " + JSON.stringify(process.env));

    //This bit is my problem child

    const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(
        this, "VPC",{
        vpcId: 'vpc-##########'
    });

    //this bit doesn't matter, I'm just showing the functions I'm calling to set everything up

    const sd_namespace = service_discovery.PrivateDnsNamespace.from_private_dns_namespace_attributes();
    const ecs_cluster = ecs.Cluster.from_cluster_attributes();
    const services_sec_grp = ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id();
    }
}

const app = new core.App();

_env = {account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION };

new Frontend(app, stack_name, {env: _env});

app.synth();
```

When I run CDK synth, it spits out:

> Error: Cannot retrieve the value from context provider vpc-provider since the account/region is not specified at the stack level. Either configure "env" with explicit account and region when you define your stack or use the environment variables "CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT" and "CDK_DEFAULT_REGION" to inherit environment information from the CLI (not recommended for production stacks)

But I don't know why. My usage here fits several other Stackoverflow answers to similar questions, it loos like the examples in the AWS docs, and when I console.log(process.env), it spits out the correct/expected values of CDK_DEFAULT_REGION and CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT. When I log "env" it spits out the expected values as well.

So my question is, how do I configure my environment so ec2.Vpc.fromLookup knows my account info, or how do I pass the values properly to "env"?

Comment: This might be useful https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#envvars-set

Comment: @Mithilesh_Kunal the environment variables are set though. When I log out `process.env`, they are there. So why does `ec2.Vpc.fromLookup` throw an error complaining about them? They are set.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand, it you *must* [specify an environment explicitly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html) if you want to use environment specifics at synth time.

> The AWS CDK distinguishes between not specifying the env property at all and specifying it using CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT and CDK_DEFAULT_REGION. The former implies that the stack should synthesize an environment-agnostic template. Constructs that are defined in such a stack cannot use any information about their environment. For example, you can't write code like if (stack.region === 'us-east-1') or use framework facilities like Vpc.fromLookup (Python: from_lookup), which need to query your AWS account. These features do not work at all without an explicit environment specified; to use them, you must specify env.

If you want to share environment variables with the cli you can do it like this:

```js
new MyDevStack(app, 'dev', { 
  env: { 
    account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT, 
    region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION 
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I was not able to comment, I am posting my query here.

From the look of it, there is just a single stack `frontend`. So I believe you can also try hard coding account-id and region in code, and see if it works.
Also I am curious what is the output of

```
console.log("environment variables " + JSON.stringify(process.env));
```

Comment: I have tried hardcoding the account id and region code as well, and I get the same result as in my post. As far as the log output, it is everything in the env, when I search through it I find CDK_DEFAULT_REGION and CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT are both set properly in the env.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the props with `env` to the parent construct constructor explicitly as mentioned by [Nick Cox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56151/nick-cox)

```js
class BasePlatform extends core.Construct {
        constructor(scope, id, props = {}) {
            super(scope, id, props);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `super(scope, id)`  with `super(scope, id, props);`

The props need to be passed to super for the vpc-provider to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to use aws cli(`aws configure`).

You will need to have programmatic access for your user and generate access keys from aws console.
[AWS CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html)
[image: required screenshot from cdk docs]

Comment: This helps, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have done this already. `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` have my account info in them, and as I said in my question, when I `console.log("environment variables " + JSON.stringify(process.env));` the correct environment variables are present in the log. However, when I actually try to use `ec2.Vpc.fromLookup` I get the error referenced above. So why specifically is `vpc-provider` unable to access this information?

Comment: Just had this problem because my super didn't use the props.

Replace your `super(scope, id);` with `super(scope, id, props);`